# How to delete all rows in all table of a database in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database

I had a database with nearly 500 tables and I want to delete all the records of all the tables. How to achieve this?

Comment: Do you want to remove all of the tables or just truncate the data within the tables?

Comment: @Nick just want to truncate all the tables

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest way is to drop and recreate the database structure using these shell commands:

```
mysqldump -d dbname > structure.sql
mysqladmin drop dbname
mysqladmin create dbname
mysql dbname < structure.sql
```

Insert mysql credentials as required, eg `-u root -psecret -h localhost`

Answer (score 3):

```
TRUNCATE tableName;
```

This will empty the contents of the table. check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454174/how-to-empty-all-rows-from-all-tables-in-mysql-in-sql)

```
<?php
mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'password');
$dbName = "database";
mysql_select_db($dbName)
$result_t = mysql_query("SHOW TABLES");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_t))
{
   mysql_query("TRUNCATE " . $row['Tables_in_' . $dbName]);
}
?>
```

Comment: Just repeat 500 times... ;)

Answer (score 2):

[check this other question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454174/how-to-empty-all-rows-from-all-tables-in-mysql-in-sql)

also, it would be useful to know if you want to use just sql or also any scripting language.