# Mysql - How to clear all data from all table in single database

Tags: mysql

I have database called **Database1** and this DB have **40 tables**. Now i want to delete all data from that 40 tables.I know that to display all tables from DB using

```
SELECT table_name 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables 
WHERE table_schema = 'Database1';
```

So how to delete all data from all tables form **Database1** using single query?

**Note :**

I should delete only data, not tables.

I am using mysql workbench 6.0

Comment: DROP Database1; CREATE Database1 and everything is empty

Comment: @BerndBuffen: That would also lose the table definitions...

Comment: SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('TRUNCATE TABLE ',t.TABLE_SCHEMA,'.',t.TABLE_NAME,';\n') SEPARATOR '') FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables t WHERE t.table_schema = 'Database1' - It deletes also views. Query the result of this

Answer (score 4):

You can try this:

```
mysqldump -d -uuser -ppass --add-drop-table yourdatabasename > yourdatabasename.sql
mysql -uuser -ppass yourdatabasename < yourdatabasename.sql
```

As pointed correctly by Zafar, if you want to include stored procedure/function also then you can include -R option.

Or you can try like

```
mysql -Nse 'show tables' yourdatabasename | while read table; do mysql -e "truncate table $yourtable" yourdatabasename; done
```

Comment: Or as one command, just pipe mysqldump ouput to mysql and do away with the intermediate file...

Comment: Re your edit using `truncate`, see the point I made on @Zafer's answer: "*Be careful—`$table` should really be quoted and escaped (it might contain characters that are invalid in unquoted identifiers).*" I find the answer using mysqldump to be much safer.

Comment: @eggyal:- Yes agreed and even I would prefer to use mysqldump. But just added one more option. :)

Comment: @RahulTripathi: ths dump technique will loose stored procedure/function so include -R also.

Comment: @RahulTripathi, please note that your method will also preserve AUTO_INCREMENT counters, unlike `TRUNCATE TABLE`. Whether that's a good thing or not, should be left for OP to consider.

Comment: @ZafarMalik: Why would it lose stored procs?  They're not being dropped anywhere...

Answer (score 0):

You can execute below command on server console.

```
mysql -uroot -p<pass> -Nse 'show tables' database1 | while read table; do mysql -uroot -p<pass> database1 -e "truncate table $table"; done
```

You  can also do it by any gui like sqlyog by below steps-

```
right click on database1 > choose more database options > truncate database
```

Third option is by structure backup and restore as per below-

```
mysqldump -R -d -uroot -proot123 database1 | mysql -uroot -proot123 database1
```

Note: `Always use -R if you are using stored procedures/function other wise you loose it.`

enjoy...

Comment: Be careful—`$table` should really be quoted and escaped (it might contain characters that are invalid in unquoted identifiers).  I find @Rahul's answer using mysqldump to be much safer.

Comment: @eggyal: without -R, mysqldump will not include sotored procedire/function in backup file.

Comment: That is true, but the sprocs/functions are never being dropped from the original database—only the tables get dropped (if you specify `--add-drop-table` option to mysqldump, which you're not doing, so actually your version will fail due to the tables already existing).

Comment: @eggyal: As per my information --add-drop-table is default with mysqldump so no need to include it....also when your backup file does not contain procedure/function schema then how they will be restored.

Comment: The database is never dropped.  The sprocs are never dropped.  So there's no need to "restore" them.

Comment: @eggyal: Yes you are correct, here tables will be dropped and re-create not database/stored procs.

Answer (score 0):

For Oracle : 
if you want to delete all the records of all the tables without drop the tables you should have  a look, it may help you
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/74519/delete-all-the-data-from-all-tables

you can try any of following :
[Delete data from all tables in MYSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885101/delete-data-from-all-tables-in-mysql)

[How to empty all rows from all tables in mysql (in sql)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454174/how-to-empty-all-rows-from-all-tables-in-mysql-in-sql)

Comment: The linked question (and its answers) is only applicable to Oracle.